# google storage BlobKeyForFile error

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to serve images from google storage via google [images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/images/)

In order to do  that i need to create blob key.

i tried  several ways togenerate the key but got errors

```
loc := fmt.Sprintf("/gs/%s/%s", BUCKET, s)
applog.Infof(appCtx, "%s", loc)
bkey, err := blobstore.BlobKeyForFile(appCtx, loc)
if err != nil {
    gc.JSON(500, model.GenericResponse{500, err.Error()})
    return
}
opt := &image.ServingURLOptions{}
u, err := image.ServingURL(appCtx, bkey, opt)
if err != nil {
    gc.JSON(500, model.GenericResponse{500, err.Error()})
    return
}

// i tried with file extension to 
/gs/bucktname/CXlvJUKiTmo9joe6
OBJECT_NOT_FOUND 

gs://bucktname/rUAJOYKQbORzOYvs
"description": "API error 6 (images: INVALID_BLOB_KEY)"

gs:/bucktname/MlY77iFNbBca2KCA
"description": "API error 6 (images: INVALID_BLOB_KEY)"
```

1. What is the correct path ?
2. Dose the images cached and behind cdn ?

Comment: I have the same problem, now.
Did you find the answer to this?

What is confusing is that it works when running on local emulated appengine but fails in the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well (among others) and here are the fixes which worked for me:

1. When saving the file to Google Cloud Storage you need to make it public like so: `writer.ACL = []storage.ACLRule{{Entity: storage.AllUsers, Role: storage.RoleReader}}`
2. The correct path is `fmt.Sprintf("/gs/%s/%s", bucketName, objectName)` where objectName is the path to the file within the bucket.
3. You have to make the bucket public. How to do that is described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets).